# Кодировка файла, получаемого php-скриптом

Tags: php, кодировка, перекодировка

Вопрос по поводу функций, связанных с кодировкой. Получаю данные curl()-ом с сайта, кодировка на котором установлена windows-1251. В скрипте-парсере есть такая строка:

```
$output = mb_convert_encoding($output, 'cp1251', 'utf-8');
```

Насколько я понимаю, cp1251 - это и есть windows-1251

Но в файле, куда я сохраняю полученные данные, **я всё равно получаю нечитаемые кракозябры** в кодировке Юникод. См скрин[image: Знаки вопроса вместо кириллицы]

Видимо, mb_convert_encoding не срабатывает почему-то.

**Подскажите, как преобразовать данные в utf-8? 
Спасибо!**

P.S. Поменяла местами 'cp1251' и 'utf-8'. Вижу изменения, но, увы, это опять не кириллица.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, вы неправильно указываете направление перекодировки. Поменяйте название кодировок местами:

```
$output = mb_convert_encoding($output, 'utf-8', 'cp1251');
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

Answer (score 0):

Задача решилась использованием функции iconv

```
$output = iconv($output, 'win-1251', 'utf-8');
```

Ура, товарищи!!!